# OOP - What is the proper definition between instance and object?

Tags: java, oop, kotlin

Is instance and object same thing in OOP or not? 
A good explanation [Here](https://alfredjava.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/class-vs-object-vs-instance/). But some explanation is so confusing. 
I want to know best explanation. Advance thanks .

Comment: There is no such thing as the objectively best explanation.  There are different explanations, and people disagree on which one is the best one.

Comment: And before you complain that this is too confusing for you and that you are unsatisfied, consider whether there is a single objective definition for "beauty", "art" or "love" ... and whether it matters.

Comment: I like your comments. From my site, I think like that. Thank you for commenting me.